# как округлить дату до дня? t-sql

Tags: sql-server

У меня есть таблица Orders(Date - время заказа с точностью до минуты. CountMaterial - количество используемых материалов)

Как мне округлить время заказа до дня. Чтобы посмотреть сколько всего материалов было использовано за день?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE);
```

вместо `getdate` подставляете вашу дату

Answer (score -1):

> to_char(Date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')

```
SELECT SUM(CountMaterial), TO_CHAR(Date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
FROM Orders
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(Date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```